# Cancelling a network storeAsnyc() task

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following async operation. When the operation completes, it calls the `dataSentHandler` function. I was wondering if I can cancel the operation after a certain time.

```
DataWriterStoreOperation dswo = networkDataWriter.StoreAsync(); 

dswo.Completed = new AsyncOperationCompletedHandler<uint>(DataSentHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can request the cancellation of the operation using `networkDataWriter.Cancel()`

You could use a timer to check for and initiate the timeout and cancel the timer if the request is successful.

```
DataWriterStoreOperation dswo = networkDataWriter.StoreAsync(); 

dswo.Completed = new AsyncOperationCompletedHandler<uint>(DataSentHandler);

Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.Elapsed += () => { networkDataWriter.Cancel(); };
timer.Start();
```

Sources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datawriterstoreoperation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx